# How to remote provision linphone?

Tags: linphone

I have a hopefully simple question, how do I get remote provisioning to work??

My setup is:

- Mac OS
- Koa server: To get config from
- Virtualbox: To install ubuntu VM on
- Ubuntu 18.04 VM: To install linphone on

The linphone in question does fetch the config from the koa server, as I can see the request coming in and the config being added to the response body.

The configs I've returned from the server to the linphone so far are:

```
[net]
download_bw=2048
upload_bw=1024
firewall_policy=ice
stun_server=stun.linphone.org

[sip]
sip_tcp_port=5070
ping_with_options=0
media_encryption=none
dscp=0x0

[proxy_0]
reg_proxy=sip.mydomain.com:5061;transport=tls
reg_expires=900
reg_sendregister=1
publish=0
dial_escape_plus=1
push_notification_allowed=1
```

And I also tried the example xml config provided on Belledonne Communications own github as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns="http://www.linphone.org/xsds/lpconfig.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.linphone.org/xsds/lpconfig.xsd lpconfig.xsd">

    <section name="proxy_default_values">
        <entry name="avpf" overwrite="true">1</entry>
        <entry name="dial_escape_plus" overwrite="true">0</entry>
        <entry name="publish" overwrite="true">0</entry>
        <entry name="quality_reporting_collector" overwrite="true">sip:voip-metrics@sip.linphone.org;transport=tls</entry>
        <entry name="quality_reporting_enabled" overwrite="true">1</entry>
        <entry name="quality_reporting_interval" overwrite="true">180</entry>
        <entry name="reg_expires" overwrite="true">31536000</entry>
        <entry name="reg_identity" overwrite="true">sip:?@sip.linphone.org</entry>
        <entry name="reg_proxy" overwrite="true">&lt;sip:sip.linphone.org;transport=tls&gt;</entry>
        <entry name="reg_sendregister" overwrite="true">1</entry>
        <entry name="refkey" overwrite="true">push_notification</entry>
        <entry name="realm" overwrite="true">sip.linphone.org</entry>
        <entry name="nat_policy_ref" overwrite="true">nat_policy_default_values</entry>
    </section>

    <section name="nat_policy_default_values">
        <entry name="stun_server" overwrite="true">stun.linphone.org</entry>
        <entry name="protocols" overwrite="true">stun,ice</entry>
    </section>

    <section name="sip">
        <entry name="rls_uri" overwrite="true">sips:rls@sip.linphone.org</entry>
        <entry name="auto_net_state_mon" overwrite="true">1</entry>
    </section>

    <section name="assistant">
        <entry name="domain" overwrite="true">sip.linphone.org</entry>
        <entry name="algorithm" overwrite="true">SHA-256</entry>
        <entry name="password_max_length" overwrite="true">-1</entry>
        <entry name="password_min_length" overwrite="true">1</entry>
        <entry name="username_length" overwrite="true">-1</entry>
        <entry name="username_max_length" overwrite="true">64</entry>
        <entry name="username_min_length" overwrite="true">1</entry>
        <entry name="username_regex" overwrite="true">^[a-z0-9+_.\-]*$</entry>
    </section>
    <section name="lime">
        <entry name="lime_server_url" overwrite="true">https://lime.linphone.org/lime-server/lime-server.php</entry>
    </section>
</config>
```

But the above configs do nothing.

Any advice on what I may have missed will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Link below can be used: https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Lib/Features/Remote%20Provisioning/